# View with MultiValueEncoded returns only one element

Tags: multiversx

My view should return multiple elements, but I always got only one.
I am calling my view with `/vm-values/query`.

Should I use another gateway endpoint for the MultiValueEncoded view?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, I used the `queryContract` function from the class `ApiNetworkProvider` in the `erdjs` npm package.

```js
const apiNetworkProvider = new ApiNetworkProvider("https://devnet-api.elrond.com");

const output = await apiNetworkProvider.queryContract({
    address: "erd1....",
    func: {
        toString(): string {
            return "myFunc";
        }
    },
    getEncodedArguments() {
        return []; // I don't need args
    },
});
```

The returnData is encoded in base64, so I decoded like so:

```js
const decodedData = output.returnData.map(data => Buffer.from(data, "base64").toString());
```